# Check if the values from a column match the range from a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

First, I am new here so I hope I will make myself clear.

So I have 2 sheets: **"Sheet1"** and **"Sheet2"**. Sheet2 has different values in **range(D2: D6**). The sheet1 **range(A2:A6)** is empty. Every time when I insert data in sheet1 range(A2:A6) it has to check if that data matches the data from sheet2 range(D2: D6). If the data matches in a cell, then it is kept in range(A2:A6), if not it is deleted from range(A2:A6).

Here is the code I made. Unfortunately, I cannot upload the Excel so you guys can see it better. The code works only when I press the bottom I created in the sheet:

```
Sub check()


Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim aRec As Worksheet, bRec As Worksheet, wb As Workbook


Dim aDesc As String, bDesc As String
Dim auxSheet1 As Variant
Dim auxSheet2 As Variant
Dim count As Integer


Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set aRec = wb.Worksheets(1)
Set bRec = wb.Worksheets(2)


For i = 2 To aRec.UsedRange.Rows.count
count = 1
auxSheet1 = Trim(aRec.Cells(i, 1).Value)
For j = 2 To bRec.UsedRange.Rows.count
auxSheet2 = Trim(bRec.Cells(j, 4).Value)

If Not auxSheet1 = auxSheet2 Then
count = count + 1
End If

If count = bRec.UsedRange.Rows.count Then
aRec.Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
End If
Next j
Next i


End Sub
```

My problem is that this code works only when I am pressing the bottom i created in the Excel file. Instead I want my code to be smarter and avoid pressing the bottom.

What I mean is that every time when an entry is entered in sheet1 range(A2:A6) the code should work automatically and delete the entries which don't match from sheet2 range(d2:d6). I want to delete the bottom and let the code to do its job automatically every time a data is inserted in range(A2:A6) - keep the data that matches, and delete the ones which don't.

Comment: Sounds like you want Data Validation.  It already exists on the Data tab.

Comment: Maybe if you explain the background and provide additional info on how exactly you want this to work someone might be able to help you out e.g. how the data will be entered, yourself of someone else, when do you want the data validation to kick in, after each cell is entered or after a set of values in A2:A6 has been entered, etc. background will help us understand your needs

Comment: The data will be entered by someone else and I want the data validation to kick in after each cell is entered i.e. if a value is inserted in A3 then the code should check if it's matching the data from sheet2 range(D2:D6)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Worksheet Change event and then you can see if the changed cells are included in the range you care about, and then process the range.

See this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel

Alternatively, you can create a UDF that takes a range, and pass in the range `A2:A6`, then each time a cell is changed, the UDF will be called and you can call your function.

```
Dim RefreshCount as Integer

Function DoRefresh(r As Range) As String
    change()
    DoRefresh = "Refresh " & RefreshCount
End Function
```

Put a formula in a cell `=DoRefresh(A2:A6)`. You can change the result to not count the refreshes if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

just a quick follow up. I made the code to somehow work. The only thing I did it was to change  **Sub check()** to **Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)**.

The problem is that my excel sheet loads really slow when I insert data in the column where the code is suppose to do its job. It takes ages for the code to load and check the entries. Is this because I have many vba code in my Excel sheet?

Note: If I copy only the code mentioned below in a new Excel sheet, the code works super fast, in a second.